# run a function which is in the html file called by ajax request by jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making an ajax request to call php file with variable. But it is not getting the value. I've called `$("#data").load("myfile.php?filename=file.xml")`

in myfile.php

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../files<?php echo $_GET['filename']; ?>",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(dataXML) {
            XML = dataXML;
            runNow();
        }

    });
```

But this two level ajax is request is not working. I've tried finding it with network debugger of browser, but this request is not made.

To simplify there is a page which is making the ajax request and loads its data to one div. That div has a `<script> </script>` . And inside it there is one another ajax request.

This second ajax request is not working and not getting the php variable value with `$_GET['filename']`.

Comment: Ya, It was my silly mistake. And removing plus showing perfect. But the second ajax request is still not made .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe a load event is called on `window` when the first AJAX call loads the new script element onto the page, so the inserted AJAX javascript is not being triggered.

Try removing the `$(window).load` wrapper and just directly call `$.ajax()`

Comment: Thanks ! That worked !! :D ! previously tried like that but at that time i forgot echo so it was not working ! Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../files/" + <?php echo $_GET['filename']; ?>,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(dataXML) {
            XML = dataXML;
            runNow();
        }

    });
```

Comment: It was a silly mistake ! Now showing perfect. but still the ajax request is not made